# is it possible to alias a port number?

Tags: networking, ip, alias

I want to run a service on a custom port (e.g. jenkins on 8080) and I prefer to access it via browser with a name I can remember, e.g. `http://localhost:jenkins` which will be an alias for `http://localhost:8080`

1. Is such a thing possible?
2. If so, will it be only an HTTP thing, or all network protocols will know of this alias?
3. Also, if (1) is true, is this feature supported on other OS (centos, windows, etc.)

Edit:

4. What are the moving parts from the moment I type in address until it gets resolved? I'm guessing that the browser parsers, and therefore there might be a browser that supports my request. After that, the parsed url is probably passed to an OS process which in turn can also implement my request and accept str instead of an int... Are any of these parts configurable in a such a way that it will  answer my need?

Comment: Where do you need this to work? Just on a handful of machines under your control? (Is "localhost" just an example, or is this really meant to apply only to one machine?)

Comment: If you decide to proxy following the other answers, give a try to Caddy (https://caddyserver.com/) which makes this very easy.

Comment: You can try [adding a custom protocol handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler#example). It might not work that well for your use-case, but it's something you can easily try out in a couple of minutes.

Comment: The concept of _well-known ports_ is important here.

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved with "reverse proxying" - so research into this field a bit.

It can't do what you're actually asking (alias a port number), but it can give you another way to make an easy path for each service (by forwarding DNS records to a specific IP and port).

Basically, what you *can* do with a reverse proxy is:

- Ensure all your sites present an SSL certificate, and (if you choose) enforce `HTTPS` in this case
- Map `http://localhost:8080` to `https://jenkins.local` (port forward)
- Map `http://localhost/jenkins` to `https://jenkins.local` (location forward)

The above works with both internal and external DNS resolving

I'm personally using [Nginx Proxy Manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/), but [Traefik](https://traefik.io/traefik/) is also a popular choice.

To get an idea what to setup, Nginx Proxy Manager looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Using HTTPS is not a prerequisite to reverse proxying. It is probably a good idea, though  (for a variety of reasons, security being one of them - but YMMV)

Comment: Agreed - but I don't believe I ever said it was a prerequisite - I gave it as an example of what you can do. However, I really can't see any reason in 2021 not to use HTTPS when possible, so you could say I'm assuming that most people want to use it.

Comment: Well, your first point states "ensure" and "enforce". In any case, the decision to use or not HTTPS is up to the administrator, I just wanted to highlight that this is not something you have to do. There are plenty of cases where it is easier (and still safe) to use HTTP.

Comment: Just to be clear, since it's non-obvious without reading the other answers: this doesn't actually do *quite* what the asker asked (which was to use a symbolic name for a port number), but that's not actually possible, and this is the *closest* thing that works and solves the underlying problem.

Comment: I agree. I was trying to give a solution to the underlying problem, as the OP states: "... and I prefer to access it via browser with a name I can remember". I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

From rfc 1738  https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738#section-3.1

port in the url is a number

> ```
> port
>
>     The port number to connect to. Most schemes designate
>     protocols that have a default port number. Another port number
>     may optionally be supplied, in decimal, separated from the
>     host by a colon. If the port is omitted, the colon is as well.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use solutions such as Nginx, Apache, squid, lighthttpd, etc.
Do note that these will map your port to whatever name you give but it will be something independent from the internal localhost. You can use this software in Linux and window based systems.

Here's an apache example.

```
Listen IP_ADDR:80
NameVirtualHost IP_ADDR:80

<VirtualHost IP_ADDR:80>
  ServerName  yourname.yourdomain

  ProxyPass        / http://localhost:10000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Another solution, if you wish to keep the servers memorable, is to give Jenkins a different IP all together by running it on a different server and then mapping it in `/etc/hosts` as `192.168.1.1 Jenkins` (You basically add this in the file). After doing this let us say your Jenkins is running on `192.168.1.1:3000` you can access it by `http://jenkins:3000`.

Even if you do this, all network protocols won't work, you won't be able to access Jenkins using `https://jenkins:3000`.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I already have IP aliases using `etc/hosts` so I was hoping for the same solution for ports as well :) Thanks!

Comment: There is /etc/services, but browsers generally don't use it, and even if they did, you'd need to implement on the client, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution is to use [`redir`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=redir) to redirect the ports, e.g. run `redir :80 127.0.0.1:8080`, or even better put it into your `inetd.conf`. If you do not like the traffic going wastefully through another process, the same can be achieved using `iptables` forwarding (but that is more hassle).

True way of creating an alias would be to use a [SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) in your DNS server and that would work well with no overhead, but because of history, *SRV records are ignored for the http/https protocol*.

Comment: Persumably he already has something else running on port 80, or he wouldn't need to use 8080 for this.

Comment: @Barmar who knows... I guess more likely it is some kind of a web framework that he runs under a non-root account. But even so, this setup is still possible if he has multiple interfaces (with separate ip addresses) available.

Comment: you're not really answering the question, you're saying that they don't need to use port 8080 in the first place. The question is just about using a name instead of number for the port.

Comment: @Barmar you are right... I mis-read the colon as a dot. In that case, I am afraid there is no server solution to the OP's requirement (no reverse proxy etc.)